# Access Django SubClass Method from SuperClass

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Okay, so I have two Django models:

```python
class Ticket(BaseModel):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/core/group/ticket/{0}/'.format(self.id)

class ProjectTicket(Ticket):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    phase = models.ForeignKey('ProjectPhase', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/different/url/structure'
```

Now, I'm querying all Ticket objects with Ticket.objects.all(). This will return all Ticket objects, including some that are ProjectTicket subclasses.

What I'd like to be able to do is access the subclass get_absolute_url() when the objects in question are actual subclassed ProjecTicket objects.

I know that I can get the parent class from the subclass, but I want to be able to do the reverse.

Has anyone achieved something like this? If so, what approach did you take?

Comment: I'm having this same issue, also having multiple subclasses, did you find some way to solve it in a "cleaner" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way that I can think of right now:

I'm sure you know that inheriting django models creates a OneToOne relationship with the parent. So, the `Ticket` objects which are also instances of `ProjectTicket` class, will have an attribute called `projectticket` on them. You can check for this value and return the url accordingly:

```
class Ticket(...):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'projectticket'):
            return self.projectticket.get_absolute_url()
        else:
            return '/core/group/ticket/{0}/'.format(self.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely the first thing I tried and works for this specific use-case, but I'm likely going to have multiple subclasses that inherit from Ticket, potentially dozens. This seems like it would get burdensome and hence why I avoided it. I should have noted that I tried it, though.

Comment: @Craig I don't think there's another way to do it. Because when you query for `Ticket` objects, the returned objects will be instances of `Ticket` class. Since a parent class has no idea of it's children, you can't call `ProjectTicket.get_absolute_url` from an instance of `Ticket`.

Comment: I think you're correct, and I'll mark it correct for the sake of other people who might have a similar , more limited, use case.